# How to find the types of method arguments upon method call?

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, roslyn, static-analysis, analyzer

Suppose we have the following base model:

```cs
public class Base
{
   ...
}
```

and have ***M<sub>1</sub>, ..., M<sub>n</sub>*** models derived from this one.

We have an interface with the following structure:

```cs
public interface IExampleInterface
{
    void DoSomething(Base input);
}
```

And suppose we have a simple implementation for this class, for example like this:

```cs
public class Example : IExampleInterface
{
   void DoSomething(Base input) 
   {
       System.Console.WriteLine("Please help me!!");
   }
}
```

There are many calls of ***IExampleInterface.DoSomething*** method with different input arguments across the solution.

```cs
var ex = new Example();
var m = new M();
ex.DoSometing(m);
```

where M can be any type from ***M<sub>1</sub>, ..., M<sub>n</sub>***.

I managed to find the interface from the syntax tree, its implementation and the parameter types, even more I found the callers, but I have trouble finding the type of passed arguments in ***IExampleInterface.DoSomething*** calls.

Here is the code:

```cs
var interfaceName = "IExampleInterface";
var returnType = "Void";
var methodName = "DoSomething";
var arg = "Base";

var exInterface = compilations
        .SelectMany(compilation => compilation.SyntaxTrees.Select(syntaxTree => compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree)))
        .SelectMany(
            semanticModel => semanticModel
                .SyntaxTree
                .GetRoot()
                .DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>()
                .Select(interfaceDeclarationSyntax => semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(interfaceDeclarationSyntax)))
        .Where(s => s.Name == interfaceName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

var implementations = await SymbolFinder.FindImplementationsAsync(exInterface, solution);
var implementation = implementations.FirstOrDefault() as ITypeSymbol;
var method = exInterface
        .GetMembers(methodName)
        .Where(m => m.Kind == SymbolKind.Method)
        .Cast<IMethodSymbol>()
        .FirstOrDefault(m =>
            m.Parameters != null &&
            m.Parameters.Length == 1 &&
            m.Parameters[0].Type.Name == arg &&
            m.ReturnType.Name == returnType);

var callers = await SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(method, solution);
```

At this point I am stuck. I am relatively new to **Roslyn**. My question is how to find the type of arguments passed to ***IExampleInterface.DoSomething*** calls?

Comment: I think that you are going to have to get the [SemanticModel](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis#the-semanticmodel), with something like **var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);** You can then use something like model.GetSymbolInfo() to get information about that symbol. I am not sure of the details.

Comment: @PhilJollans Dear Phil, thanks for your suggestion. I actually solved the issue with the help of semantic model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the issue by getting **semantic model** of the compilations.

Firstly, after finding all the callers we need to find ***InvocationExpression*** nodes with the help of ***CallingSymbol*** from **SymbolCallerInfo**.

Secondly, we must get the argument we are interested in from ***ArgumentList*** property of ***InvocationExpression***.

Suppose that ***arg*** is the desired argument and ***compilation*** is the Compilation instance where the ***arg*** is from.

```cs
var type = compilation
      .GetSemanticModel(arg.SyntaxTree)
      .GetTypeInfo(arg.ChildNodes().First());
```